# NodeJS Express with SSL not working with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx, proxy

While I am setting up a NodeJS app on Ubuntu 16.04, I have faced some strange behaviour. App is only works with http dependency but not with https dependency.

My NodeJS app is running on port 8081 and I'm using Nginx reverse proxy with SSL to redirect calls to the 8081 port. Following is my `default.conf` file in Nginx `site-enabled` directory.

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy requests on to local Node.js app:
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name test.com;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Pass requests for / to localhost:8081:
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Following is the test script I'm running on Node server.

```
var https = require('https');
https.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Welcome to Test App');
}).listen(8081, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8081/');
```

I'm getting `502 Bad Gateway` when I test site using `test.com`.
But strangely when I change the `https` dependency to http everything works like a charm.

What might be the issue for the strange behaviour? Can't we use https with SSL setup with Nginx? 
Since I'm looking to use trusted peer connection it's necessary to use https with NodeJS as well.

Comment: Does the nginx error log (in `/var/log/nginx`) reveal anything? Also, if you don't use any forwarding, can you access the nginx default homepage without any issue?

Comment: Also, from what I see you are broadcasting on `https://localhost:8081/` (despite not configuring security keys on the node server for your test) but forwarding to non-https URL at `http://localhost:8081/`

Comment: @nb1987 There is one.

23828#23828: *32 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.123.106.254, server: test.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "test.com"

Comment: Okay...I just have a couple more questions. 1.) Is the value of `proxy_pass` still `http://localhost:8081/;` ? Do you still get the same error if you set it to `https://localhost:8081/;` ? 2.) Can you see what error Node itself throws? You can assign the result of `http.createServer` to a variable and listen for error: e.g., `var server = http.createServer(function ... ` then `server.on('error', function (e) { console.log(e); });`

Comment: I just set it to `https://localhost:8081/` and it's working. I have tried this before but didn't work. It's working now. Please add as an answer to accept it.

Comment: Great to hear it is working! Perhaps the first time you changed it you did not restart your Nginx server? (Just a guess as to why it did not work the first time.) I have added my answer as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Node.js application is listening on https, your Nginx server should forward requests to `https://localhost:8081/` rather than `http://localhost:8081`, so you should set your `proxy_pass` value to `https://localhost:8081/`

Comment: This works fine until I add SSL options in the NodeJS.
`var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(config.keypath),
  ca: [fs.readFileSync(config.capath)], 
  cert: fs.readFileSync(config.certpath), 
  requestCert: true, 
  rejectUnauthorized: true
};` With this code specially when I add `requestCert: true` this error start happening again.

Comment: Do connections work OK (either directly or through Nginx) without `requestCert`? Also, the default setting for `requestCert` is `false` and in typical configurations it will indeed be `false`. But, if you are certain that you need it set to `true`, I would recommend trying to find out what errors Node itself reports. Could you try listening for the `error` event by adding one such event listener to your server using the sample code I provided in the comments to your initial question? In that case, what error does Node report?

Comment: I used it. There are no errors. NodeJS script is working fine at `test.com:8081` but not on naked domain when I use `requestCert: true`. I need to use this as I want only the users with the certificate to access it.

Comment: To be honest in my own applications I have never exposed the Node server to the outside so I have only needed to configure TLS/SSL on the Nginx server. However, I suspect that in this scenario you would need to authenticate Nginx to the upstream server by setting the `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` directives under your `location /` block. This guide may be of help: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/